# use group by to get n smallest values but with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I have pandas DataFrame like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,4],'value':[1,1,1,1,3,1,2,2,3,3,4,1,1]})
>>> df
id  value
1      1
1      1
1      1
1      1
1      3
2      1
2      2
2      2
2      3
2      3
2      4
3      1
4      1
```

I want to get a new DataFrame with top 2 (well really n values) values for each id *including* duplicates, like this:

```
   id  value
0   1      1
1   1      1
3   1      1
4   1      1
5   1      3
6   2      1
7   2      2
8   2      2
9   3      1
10  4      1
```

I've tried using head() and nsmallest() but I think those will not include duplicates. Is there a better way to do this?

Edited to make it clear I want more than 2 records per group if there are more than 2 duplictes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) in first step, then get top values and last use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['id','value']).sort_values(['id','value']).groupby('id').head(2)
df = df.merge(df1)
print (df)
   id  value
0   1      1
1   1      1
2   1      2
3   1      2
4   2      1
5   2      2
6   2      2
7   3      1
8   4      1
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,4],'value':[1,1,1,1,3,1,2,2,3,3,4,1,1]})
    
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['id','value']).sort_values(['id','value']).groupby('id').head(2)
df = df.merge(df1)
print (df)
   id  value
0   1      1
1   1      1
2   1      1
3   1      1
4   1      3
5   2      1
6   2      2
7   2      2
8   3      1
9   4      1
```

Or use custom lambda function with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('id')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.isin(sorted(set(x))[:2]))]
print (df)
    id  value
0    1      1
1    1      1
2    1      2
3    1      2
5    2      1
6    2      2
7    2      2
11   3      1
12   4      1
```

---

```
df = df[df.groupby('id')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.isin(sorted(set(x))[:2]))]
print (df)
    id  value
0    1      1
1    1      1
2    1      1
3    1      1
4    1      3
5    2      1
6    2      2
7    2      2
11   3      1
12   4      1
```

Comment: would this capture three ID = 1 and Value = 1 if there were 3 of them? or like 50?

Comment: @Jogianni - My solution get first 2 unique values per groups with duplicates, do you need something else?