# Pandas drop last duplicate record and keep remaining

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

have a pandas dataframme with columns name , school and marks

```
name  school  marks

tom     HBS     55
tom     HBS     54
tom     HBS     12
mark    HBS     28
mark    HBS     19
lewis   HBS     88
```

How to drop last duplicate row and keep reamining data

```
name  school  marks

tom     HBS     55
tom     HBS     54
mark    HBS     28
lewis   HBS     88
```

tried this:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['name','school'],keep=last)


print(df)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use group by to get n smallest values but with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63282258/use-group-by-to-get-n-smallest-values-but-with-duplicates)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Pandas, how do I drop the last row of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670941/using-pandas-how-do-i-drop-the-last-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to drop only the last duplicate, you need to use two masks:

```
m1 = df.duplicated(['name','school'], keep="last") # is it the last row per group?
m2 = ~df.duplicated(['name','school'], keep=False) # is it not duplicated?
new_df = df[m1|m2]
```

output:

```
    name school  marks
0    tom    HBS     55
1    tom    HBS     54
3   mark    HBS     28
5  lewis    HBS     88
```

Answer (score 0):

I extrapolated  @DSM's answer(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670941/using-pandas-how-do-i-drop-the-last-row-of-each-group)) taking into account that you want rows with no duplicates:

```
df.groupby("name", as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x if len(x)==1 else x.iloc[:-1]).reset_index()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using `groupby`+`apply` is very slow